# How to post multipart/form-data to website using C# windows application

Tags: c#

Can anybody help me resolve the problem for posting multipart/form-data using below code.

I have no idea about how to do it.

Please refer function PostTrivialData from post [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974468/why-do-i-receive-this-error-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-417-expectat)

Comment: yes we can also write the application for you.

Comment: Check the answer for that question. I think that is what exactly you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Code for Posting multipart data to URI:

```
public string UploadChatFile(Stream fileStream, string uri, string postData, string fileName)
        {
            string boundary = "----------------------------" +
            DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");

            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            httpWebRequest2.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" +
            boundary;
            httpWebRequest2.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest2.KeepAlive = true;


            Stream memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            byte[] boundarybytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");

            memStream.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);

            string headerTemplate = string.Format("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"postdata\"\r\n{0}\r\n\r\n", postData);

            byte[] headerbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(headerTemplate);

            memStream.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length);

            memStream.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);

            headerTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\n Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";

            //string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, "file" + i, files[i]);
            string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, "uplTheFile", fileName);

            headerbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);

            memStream.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length);


            //FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int bytesRead = 0;

            while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                memStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

            }
            memStream.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);
            fileStream.Close();

            httpWebRequest2.ContentLength = memStream.Length;
            Stream requestStream = httpWebRequest2.GetRequestStream();
            memStream.Position = 0;
            byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[memStream.Length];
            memStream.Read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
            memStream.Close();
            requestStream.Write(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            WebResponse webResponse2 = httpWebRequest2.GetResponse();

            Stream stream2 = webResponse2.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(stream2);

            string responseString = reader2.ReadToEnd();


            return responseString;
        }
```

This will post image and also you can include your data to postData parameter. You need to handle this PostData server carefully as it's combined with multipart content data.

Comment: How can i send other form fields suppose i have form with FName,LName, Phone and Photo of the user I need to post all these 4 fields 3-forms fields and 1 Image. The above code does have provision for form fields.

Comment: You can include your form data to headerTemplate. You need to handle this data server side. Another way is to include as a query string for URL.

Comment: Thanks Mohan, the above code works for standalone file upload. In my case i need to upload file along with some form filed.  If you look at the this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974468/why-do-i-receive-this-error-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-417-expectat answer post by Jason Larke work for me but i need add one more filed as file can u please help me to update that code.

Comment: I have edited code to include post string along with image.

Comment: Thanks Mohan, code work for me